# ElasticSearch: Sort Aggregations by Filtered Average

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch index with documents structured like this:

```
"created": "2019-07-31T22:44:41.437Z",
"id": "2956",
"rating": 1
```

If I wish to create an aggregation of the `id` fields which is sorted on the average of the rating, that could be handled by:

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "sorted" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "id",
        "order" : { "sort" : "asc" }
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "sort" : {
          "avg" : {
            "field" : "rating"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm looking to only factor in documents which have a `created` value that was within the last week (and then take the average of those `rating` fields).

My naive thoughts on this would be to apply a filter or range within the `sort` aggregation, but an aggregation cannot have multiple types, and looking through the [avg documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html), I don't see a means to put it in the avg.  Optimistically attempting to put range fields in the avg regardless of what the documentation says yielded no results (as expected).

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a bool query to the body with a range query:

```
{
   query:
      bool: {
         must: {
             "range": {
                 "created_time": {
                    "gte": one_week_ago,
                 }
             }
         }
     }
},
{
  "aggs" : {
    "sorted" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "id",
        "order" : { "sort" : "asc" }
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "sort" : {
          "avg" : {
            "field" : "rating"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course... this makes perfect sense.  For some reason I was trying to handle it all in aggs.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

and you can query for dynamic dates like this
as Tom referred but use "now-7d/d"

```
{
   query:
      bool: {
         must: {
             "range": {
                 "created_time": {
                    "gte": "now-7d/d"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```